# NullPointerException in Android JNI HelloJni Application

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When I'm trying to execute

```
javah -classpath NDK1_29jan/bin/classes;/home/XXXXX/Android_Eclipse_9sept/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-15/android.jar -o HelloJNI.h com.example.hellojni.HelloJni
```

Then, it is showing exception in console

```
Error: no classes specified
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Where NDK1_29jan is my project name. I already set path in `.bashrc` file like this:

```
 $export NDK=~/home/XXXXX/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d
```

Comment: It looks like you may have to specify `Main-Class: <Your Main Java class>` (without the '<' and '>') in one of your jars' `META-INF/Manifest.MF`....

Comment: is so file generated?